# Adding number label on top of an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**EDIT**

I've added this css to `span.label` using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc8jc/2/)

```
span.label{

        width:100px; color:#FFFFFF; 
        background-color:#F43B05; 
        float:right; padding:3px; 
        position:absolute; top:50px; left:5px;
}
```

And I've got this:

[image]

I need to put a label on an image using bootstrap.

I have this image with a label:

[image]

And here is the code for it:

```
<span class="label label-success">4</span>

<input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="oone" name="one" alt="button"/>

<div title="3rd Molar - Upper Rigth Jaw" id="div_one" class="collapse"><?php echo $resTeeth['one'] ?>

</div>
```

But this is not what I want. What I want is to add this number `4` green label on top of the image and not on the side of it.

I tried this:

```
<span class="label label-danger">4
<input class="img1" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="oone" name="one" alt="button"/>
<div title="3rd Molar - Upper Rigth Jaw" id="div_one" class="collapse"><?php echo $resTeeth['one'] ?>
</div>
</span>
```

And I've got this:

[image]

Comment: I edited my question, you can see what I tried

Comment: You could put the span inside the relative positioned div and then position the span absolute. You could also do it with css, using :after with the number "4" as content.

Comment: Okay, see my edit now at the top of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure this will be your answer.
Thanks

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.badge-notify{
   background-color:red !important;
   position:relative;
   top: -20px;
   left: -35px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-link" style="font-size:36px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span>
  </button>
  <span class="badge badge-notify">3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `float:left` for `span.label` and then set margins to set the position of the label element.

Comment: CSS: 
span.label {
display:block;
float:left;
margin-bottom: //here type your pixel value
margin-left: //here type your pixel value
}

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="" />
   <span class="lbl">something</span>
</div>

.container{
position:relative;
}
.container img, .container .lbl{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made two examples here, like the ones I suggested in the comments.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pymw6szw/3/)

```
div
{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

span
{
  position: absolute;
 background: red;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 55px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}  

.icon
{
  position: relative;
}

.icon:after
{
  content:"4";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 55px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```